# How to suck particles

Tags: animation, particles

How do I get the particles from the emitter get sucked into an object? Like a black hole effect.

I'm using a force field with negative values and the particles go in but go back out the other side I want it to just go in and stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a sphere on the way, add collision to it and check kill particles in collision settings